# Recognizing the subordinate conjunction

Tags: subordinate-clauses

I read that we can't use any subordinate clause at the beginning of our phrase.

I would like to know any advice to recognize them. Any memorization trick? 
If there are any, learning them by heart is the only way to recognize them?

Comment: Subordinate clause is always connected to a word in the main clause.  That word ought to be a noun or a pronoun, often an object.  If you can find the word to which the subclause is linked, you've determined that the clause is subordinate.

Comment: It's been a week without a decent answer for some reason.  Try reading this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)#Starting_a_sentence , perhaps it can give you ideas where else to look.

Comment: @VictorBazarov One possible reason that there is no good answer yet is that no one has ever heard the rule stated by the OP before ("we can't use any subordinate clause at the beginning of our phrase"). The more common rule is "Never begin a sentence with a conjunction", which is mostly about coordinating conjunctions (not subordinate, not clause). Another possible reason is that to answer the OP satisfactorily, one may need to go into details about clauses, conjunctions, sentence constructions, and then prove why the rule is incorrect (but useful, if one knows why the rule exists).

Comment: @VictorBazarov Defining relative clause (NOT, non-defining relative clause) is the Subordinate Clause which is always connected to its antecedent (a noun or a pronoun) in the main clause.

Answer (score -1):

Subordinate clauses typically start with conjunctions (of, from, to, ...) and cannot stand alone as sentences. They are most often seen at the ends of sentences, but I don't agree that they *cannot* be at the beginnings. It's just that it can be trickier sometimes to get right/make clear.

The subordinate clause here starts with "to":

- You gave the book *to whom*?.

Note that this version has the same meaning and is equally clear

- *To whom* did you give the book?.

Comment: In what universe is "from" a conjunction?

Comment: @VictorBazarov  Probably in the one where "now on" is a clause.

Comment: "Because breathing is something we do automatically, we rearly think about it."
(From English Grammar Today - Cambridge)
Here the Subordinate Clause has been put at the beginning of the sentence to give extra focus to the reason.

Besides, the Subordinate Clauses ( which are known as Subordinate Adverbial Clauses in traditional grammar) can be placed at the beginning of the sentence before the matrix clause.
e.g., Though he was rich, he was not happy.
"Though he was rich" is the Subordinate Clause.